# How to check dynamically check boxes on which i taped in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

When I tapped one checkbox, it automatically checked all the checkboxes and vice-versa unchecked all when I unchecked. But I want to specify which tapped checkbox can be checked or unchecked. How to do this please?

Here are my Flutter code and image.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Checked Listview',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Checked Listview'),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> _list = [];
  List<String> _listString = ["Ac","Fuel Sensor","Power","Panic","Camera","Relay","Duty Button","Other"];
 // var singleline;
  bool selected = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < _listString.length; i++) {
        _list.insert(0, '${_listString[i]}');
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Checked Listview'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          _list.isNotEmpty
              ? Wrap(
            children: _list
                .map(
                  (item) => IntrinsicWidth(
                child: Container(
                  width: 120,
                  height: 40,
                  child: Card(
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Checkbox(value: selected,
                                onChanged:(bool val){
                                  setState(() {
                                    selected = val;
                                  });}),
                            Expanded(child: Text(item)),
                          ],
                        ),),),),),),)
                .toList(),
          )
              : Container(),
        ],),);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Neelu, Thanks for posting in stackoverflow, please post the image instead of description .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `List<bool> selected` to control each value 
code snippet

```
List<bool> selected = [];
...
for (int i = 0; i < _listString.length; i++) {
        _list.insert(0, '${_listString[i]}');
        selected.insert(0, false);
      }
...
var index = _list.indexOf(item);
...
Checkbox(
        value: selected[index],
        onChanged: (bool val) {
          setState(() {
            selected[index] = val;
          });
        }),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Checked Listview',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Checked Listview'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> _list = [];
  List<String> _listString = [
    "Ac",
    "Fuel Sensor",
    "Power",
    "Panic",
    "Camera",
    "Relay",
    "Duty Button",
    "Other"
  ];
  // var singleline;
  List<bool> selected = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < _listString.length; i++) {
        _list.insert(0, '${_listString[i]}');
        selected.insert(0, false);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Checked Listview'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          _list.isNotEmpty
              ? Wrap(
                  children: _list.map(
                    (item) {
                      var index = _list.indexOf(item);
                      return IntrinsicWidth(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 120,
                          height: 40,
                          child: Card(
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Checkbox(
                                        value: selected[index],
                                        onChanged: (bool val) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            selected[index] = val;
                                          });
                                        }),
                                    Expanded(child: Text(item)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```